# Is "as" in "NativeScript allows you to write logic in C or C++ in a similar fashion as you would write a GDScript file." a conjunction?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, conjunctions

I got contradictory answers from bing chat to a question.
First part of the chat:
[image: topic1]

So I started a new topic
[image: topic2]

The queston is:
"NativeScript allows you to write logic in C or C++ in a similar fashion **as** you would write a GDScript file."
Is "as" in the above sentance a conjunction?

Comment: *Similar* normally is followed by *to* (here "a similar fashion to the way..."); nonetheless I think what you write is quite a common usage which avoids extra words. It depends if you want to be hyper-correct, or are writing more casually. You can Google and check out examples; I can't find strong guidance either way.

Comment: The simple answer is **No**. Superficially, there may appear to be some resemblance, but "as" is a preposition in a comparative construction, not a conjunction.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, particularly of giant blocks of text.  They can't be searched, and they're unfriendly to people using screen readers or other forms of assistive technology.  Copy and paste the particular parts that you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 'as' is a conjunction as it splits two clauses in a complex sentence. The first clause

> NativeScript allows you to write logic in C or C++ in a similar fashion.

makes sense as a whole sentence. However, the second part

> As you would write a GDScript file

does not make sense as a whole sentence. 'as' is a subordinating conjunction.


I would recommend searching for 'isawawabub' on google (it's a way to remember subordinating conjunctions).